# Navigation bar not working properly under UIPageController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement pagination in my application.
for that, I have created one UIPageViewController and added multiple view controller under the UIPageViewController.

for adding controller in UIPageViewController, I have used following code.

```
let page1: SPWalkController! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "walkid") as! SPWalkController

let page2: SPCreateWalkController! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createwalkid") as! SPCreateWalkController

    page1.isCreateWalk = true
    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)

   // Create the page container
    pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    pageContainer.delegate = self
    pageContainer.dataSource = self
    pageContainer.setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    // Add it to the view
    view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)
```

but the problem is added controller view showing under the navigation bar.
for that reason, I have deselected property "Under top bar" of Container controller. So my issue resolved. but when I have tried to present another view controller on that view controller and dismissed it again it shows it's sub view controller under the navigation bar.

Here are my screenshots of facing issue

*First screenshot before present another view controller on it*
[image]

*presented another viewcontroller*
[image]

*After dismissal above view controller it looks like following.*

*The view goes under the navigation bar*
[image]
How can I resolve this issue? or implement UIPageViewController is there any guideline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I have presented view controller on root view controller. so now it is working properly.

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```